# How can I use 5x5filter (Xilinx block), it keeps telling me there is an error in the counter?

Tags: matlab, simulink, xilinx, virtex

I'm trying to apply edge filter to an image using Xilinx blocks,

I used 5x5 buffer then I connected the 5x5filter  to it.

But it keeps telling me:

> Illegal Period, This blocks attempts to set period that is a non-integer multiple of the system rate
>   Error occurred during "Block Configuration".'

which I did not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar such problem(with solution) is posted in Xilinx Forum. Go through the link given below:

http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/DSP-Tools/Can-any-1-help-me-regarding-FIR-implementation-in-system/m-p/33650#M1463

Answer (score 0):

It means that the sample time of one of the block isn't an integer multiple of the model's minor timestep. Check the configuration parameters for the model and the parameters of your new blocks.

I don't think this has anything to do with the Xilinx blocks specifically.